# SOCKS-5 proxy server on android device without root

Tags: android, proxy, socks

Is there a way to create a SOCKS-5 proxy server on an unrooted android device? Why does it require root? Can I make my own android application that will create a server on my device and use this server as proxy on my compluter, all this without rooting the device?

**UPDATE:** I came to using [this](http://jsocks.sourceforge.net/) library to try to create a proxy server. I downloaded all files, but added only main .jar file to the project dependencies in AndroidStudio. There I am trying to start the server from a runnable in a service. Here is the service code:

```
public class ProxyService extends Service 
{

    private static boolean running = false;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        ServerAuthenticatorNone auth = new ServerAuthenticatorNone();

        ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(auth);

        Run(server); //runnable is needed because if I start service from 
                     //this thread it throws a network on main thread exception
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void Run(ProxyServer server) {
        if (running)
            return;

        final ProxyServer serverFinal = server;
        running = true;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    Log.i("DEBUG", "tick " + running);

                    serverFinal.start(1080);

                    Log.i("DEBUG", "proxyServer started at port 1080");
                    running = true;
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        running = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I run this code on my Xiaomi Redmi Note 2 unrooted device, I get the following logs:

```
07-26 16:48:18.097: I/DEBUG(19766): tick true
07-26 16:48:18.099: I/XiaomiFirewall(1211): firewall pkgName:com.socks.server, result:0
```

And when I check proxy using [this](http://www.checker.freeproxy.ru/checker/) website I get nothing.

I think I should have configured the server somehow, but it is done using external .properties file that is outside of the .jar and I do not know how to link them in an AndroidStudio project.

I also suspect that even these actions require superuser(root) to prevent Xiaomi firewall from refusing me in starting the server.

Any advice?

Comment: Hi, did you find any solutions?

Comment: @HankMoody Hi, unfortunately not.